# javaScript a traves de fecha de nacimiento verificar si es mayor de edad

Tags: javascript, html, date, condiciones, validación

Validar fecha de nacimiento, permitiendo sólo una persona mayor de edad, notificando al usuario en caso de no cumplir dicha condición y no permitir Enviar los datos.

con este label

```
<label>Fecha nacimiento:</label><input type='Date' value='' id="fechanaci" required ></div>
```

y este codigo para tomar el valor del label

```
<form onsubmit = "return validaedad(document.getElementById('fechanaci').value)">
```

hice esta funcion js

```
function validaedad (fecha_naci) {
    
    var resta
    
    var valores = fecha_naci.split ("-");
    var dia_naci = valores [2];
    var mes_naci = valores [1];
    var anio_naci = valores [0];
    
    
    var fecha_act = new Date();
    var dia_act = fecha_act.getDate();
    var mes_act = fecha_act.getMonth() + 1;
    var anio_act = fecha_act.getFullYear();
    
    resta = (parseFloat(fecha_naci) - parseFloat(fecha_act);
    
    if (resta < 18) {
        document.getElementById('fechanaci').value = {alert('es menor de edad');} 
    }
    return true;
}
```

pero no funciona y no da alerta de que es menor de edad. que me falta?

Answer (score 1):

Tomando tú código como base, tu problema solo está en la operación del calculo de la variable **resta**, te ofrezco una operación de la variable **resta** para calcular si la persona ya es mayor de edad en base a los meses que lleva viviendo, si deseas ser más especifico e ir hasta los/el día que nació solo debes ajustar un poco más el calculo de la variable **resta**.

Cabe mencionar que hay múltiples maneras de realizar o considerar este calculo, depende de que tan estricto deseas ser.

```js
 function validaedad (fecha_naci) {
      if(!fecha_naci){
           alert('ingrese fecha');
           return false;
      }
      var resta;

      var valores = fecha_naci.split ("-");
      var dia_naci = valores [2];
      var mes_naci = valores [1];
      var anio_naci = valores [0];

      var fecha_act = new Date();

      var dia_act = fecha_act.getDate();
      var mes_act = fecha_act.getMonth() + 1;
      var anio_act = fecha_act.getFullYear();
        
      // Solo voy a considerar hasta el mes para tomarlo como mayor de edad, tu puedes aumentar la especificación aumentando a la operación la sustracción de la diferencia de días.
      // sí deseas consideras los días en el if vas a tener que ir hasta los días que sería 18*12*365 entonces if ( resta < (18*12*365) ) {...}
      // resta (considerando hasta los meses) = diferencia de años (los meses que ha vivido la persona entonces *12) - (meses que le falta para su mes de nacimiento)
      // resta (considerando hasta los días) = diferencia de años (*12 *365) - diferencia de meses (*30) - diferencia de días.

      resta = (anio_act - anio_naci) * 12 - (mes_act - mes_naci);
        
      if ( resta  <  (18*12) ) {
           alert('es menor de edad');
      }
      return true;
 }
```

```html
 <div>
      <label>Fecha nacimiento:</label><input type='Date' value='' id="fechanaci" required >
      <br/>
      <button onclick="validaedad(document.getElementById('fechanaci').value)">Validar Fecha</button>
 </div>
```